# Clarifying definitions of closed sets and isolated points

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have a set of points, a closed ball and a point $\vec a$ that is isolated, all in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So I get this set, say $A$, by union of that closed ball and this isolated point $\vec a$ that's not in the closed ball.

Is this a closed set? By the definition of my book, this seems closed because the book says a set is closed if for all $\vec x \not \in$ the set, $\vec x$ is an exterior point.

But I think this isolated point is also a limit point. This is where I get confused too. By definition an isolated point is a point that is not limit point. I don't get this definition. Couldn't my isolated point be a limit point. I can think of a sequence of points in $A$ with limit in $A$, ie. the isolated point $\vec a$.

So, is this isolated point also a limit point and is this set $A$ closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set $C$ in a topological space $X$ is **closed** if for every $x\in X\setminus C$, there exists an open set $U$ such that $x\in U \subseteq X\setminus C$.

A point $x$ in a subspace $S$ of a topological space $X$ is an **isolated point of $S$** if there exists an open set $U$ such that $U\cap S = \{x\}$.

A point $x$ is a **limit point of a subspace $S$** of a topological space $X$ if every open set $U$ which contains $x$ satisfies $U\cap (S\setminus\{x\})\ne\emptyset$.

Let's notice something right away:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $S\subseteq X$, and $x\in S$. Then $x$ is an isolated point of $S$ iff $x$ is not a limit point of $S$.

*Proof:*
Since $x\in S$ by hypothesis, we have that $x$ is an isolated point of $S$ iff there exists $U$ open such that $U\cap S=\{x\}$ iff there exists $U$ open containing $x$ such that $U\cap(S\setminus\{x\})=\emptyset$ iff $x$ is not a limit point of $S$. $\square$

So if we have a closed ball $B$ and a point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B$, then the union $A:=B\cup\{x\}$ is a closed set, $x$ is an isolated point of $B$, and $x$ is not a limit point of $B$.

Comment: But why are we making the definition of limit point so that it exactly leaves out isolated point. Suppose we are studying topology of $R^n$ here. Can't that isolated point be also a limit of a sequence, the one where all terms are that isolated point?

Comment: @meguli That's the definition of limit point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point. It is indeed the limit of its own constant sequence, but that doesn't make it a limit point of the set. To call $x$ a limit point of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you must be able to construct a sequence of points in $S\setminus\{x\}$ which converge to $x$.

Comment: And one other thing, these definitions make that isolated point included in closure of the set $A$ I was talking about in the question. But isn't closure the same as the set of limit points, which does not include that isolated point?

Comment: @meguli The closure of $A$ is the union of $A$ and its limit points. We don't throw away the isolated points when taking closure. We just add in the points which are limit points. For instance, in $\mathbb{R}$, the closure of $(0,1]\cup\{2\}$ is $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$.

Comment: So the isolated points are in closure, am I right? Because my book has an exercise saying "Show that closure of $A$ is equal to limit points of $A$" which I don't know how can I do if isolated points are indeed in the closure.

Comment: @meguli Perhaps your book is using a different definition of "limit point" as you've alluded.

Answer (score 0):

A union $A$ of a closed ball $B$ and a set $\{x\}, x \notin B$ is closed as a finite union of closed sets.

$x$ is an isolated point of $A$, as $\{x\} = (X\setminus B) \cap A$ which is open in $A$, because $B$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's not a limit point of $A$.
In fact, by definition, all points of $A$ are limit points except the isolated points of $A$. So in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A' = B \subseteq A$, so $A$ is also closed by the definition that a set is closed iff it contains all its limit points.